# How can I access the URL of a Symfony Http Client response?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-client

With the Symfony Http Client I create a HTTP request like this:

```
 $client = HttpClient::create();

 $response = $client->request('GET', 'www.mypage.com', [
 'auth_basic' => ['user', '123'],
 ]);

 dump($response);
```

The output is:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Response\CurlResponse {#1117 ▼
  response_headers: []
  http_code: 0
  error: null
  url: www.something.com
  ....
```

Now I try to output the `url` of that response:

```
 dump($response->getContent());
```

But the output is `null`.

How can I get as an output the url `www.something.com`?

Comment: Seems like [`getInfo`](https://github.com/symfony/http-client/blob/5.x/Response/CurlResponse.php#L205) would be the method that returns the `url`. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the `HttpClient` responses implement the `ResponseInterface`, defined on Symfony Contracts.

That interface declares a `getInfo()` method, as shown [here](https://github.com/symfony/contracts/blob/5df50970119df94317565e294ac718494087c08d/HttpClient/ResponseInterface.php#L108).

This method returns an array, and the effective URL of the response is stored at `url` key.

```
$finalUrl = $response->getInfo()['url'];
```

Not that if the request went through one or more HTTP redirects, the final resolved URL may not be the same as the one originally requested.